# Как создать массив классов С++

Tags: c++, классы, map

Хочу писать что-то вроде

```
class Element{};
registerClass("element", &Element);

class TextNode{}
registerClass("text", &TextNode);
```

а дальше делать так

```
TextNode text = crateInstance("text");
Element element = crateInstance("element");
```

следовательно функция `registerClass` должна сохранять классы в `map`
как мне указать тип этой карты?

```
map<string, ???> classesMap;
```

или С++ настолько слабый язык что в нем нельзя сохранить ссылку на класс?

Comment: Не ясно, что вы хотите сделать. Пул готовых экземпляров? Или просто динамически создавать экземпляры классов?

Comment: Я хочу сделаь массив ссылок на классы, фраза "классы" отличается от фразы "экземпляры классов"

Comment: В С++ классы обьекты первого класса? Я могу их куда-то СОХРАНЯТЬ?

Comment: в C++ объявления классов существуют только до момента компиляции программы. Сохранить куда-то объявление класса невозможно.

Comment: я хочу засовывать классы в массив, а потом создавать этими классами экземпляры классов. я могу засовывать классы куда либо в С++?

Comment: понял, спасибо. попробую тогда проникнуться духом С++ и попытаться сделать в его стиле. а не в стиле JS) спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ну, можно хранить, например, фабрики классов - указатели на функции, которые будут создавать экземпляры нужного класса, с приведением к нужному типу... Т.е. извратиться-то можно, но вот нужно ли?

Comment: С конструктивными предложениями улучшения дизайна — на meta.stackexchange.com, не к нам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ: в С++ классы лишь условность описывающая структуры данных, и она исчезает во время работы программы, по этому сослаться на них не возможно. Иными словами нельзя сохранить класс куда либо, а потом создавать им экземпляры. Если у вас возникает такая необходимость, скорее всего вы используете приемы которые остались у вас от javascript и прочих динамичных языков. Попробуйте проникнуться духом С++ и почувствовать его стиль. И изменить архитектуру программы чтобы убрать потребность в таком сохранении классов. Разработчик должен ЯВНО знать где какой класс используется на момент написания программы. В этом и дух С++.

Answer (score 0):

Опишу код на уровне концепции:

```
class instanciable {
    public:
       virtual ~instanciable() { }
       virtual instanciable *newInstance() = 0;
}

class Factory {
   map<string, instanciable *> registeredClasses;
   public:
      ~Factory() {
          // delete all registered classes
          // ...
      }

      instanciable *newInstance(string className) {
           if (registeredClasses->find(className) != registeredClasses.end()) {
              return registeredClasses[className]->newInstance();
           }
           throw;
      } 

      void register(string className, instanciable *newclass) {
           map[className] = newclass;
      }
}

class Class1 : public instanciable {
   public:
    // ....
    virtual instanciable *newInstance() {
         return new Class1();
    }
    // ....
}

class Class2 : public instanciable {
   public:
    // ....
    virtual instanciable *newInstance() {
         return new Class2();
    }
    // ....
}

void main() {
   Factory factory();
   factory.register("Class1", new Class1());
   factory.register("Class2", new Class2());


   Class1 *cl1 = factory.newInstance("Class1");
   Class2 *cl2 = factory.newInstance("Class2");

   // ....
   cl1->method1();
   // ....
   // delete cl1, cl2
}
```

Таким образом, мы всегда держим в памяти 1 объект некоторого класса, который способен создавать сам себя. Классы этих объектов имплементируют общий интерфейс, чтобы мы могли сохранять их в `map`.